# Самоучитель по JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Подскажите хороший самоучитель javascript. Было бы хорошо со ссылкой. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обратите внимание на вопрос: самоучитель для начинающих - он отвечает на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

- [javascript](http://javascript.ru/): все подробно и с примерами.
- [jquery](http://jquery.page2page.ru): хороший справочник с примерами.